# Remove top header of Shiny application deployed on ShinyApps

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have deployed an application on ShinyApps, but my application has an extra header when deployed.

The header looks like this:

[image]

However, I would like to remove this header when the application is deployed. Is it possible to do this? I am using a sample shiny web application from the tutorials.

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

# Rely on the 'WorldPhones' dataset in the datasets
# package (which generally comes preloaded).
library(datasets)

# Define a server for the Shiny app
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({

    # Render a barplot
    barplot(WorldPhones[,input$region]*1000, 
            main=input$region,
            ylab="Number of Telephones",
            xlab="Year")
  })
})
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

# Rely on the 'WorldPhones' dataset in the datasets
# package (which generally comes preloaded).
library(datasets)

# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(

  # Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
  fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
    titlePanel("Telephones by region"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      

      # Define the sidebar with one input
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("region", "Region:", 
                    choices=colnames(WorldPhones)),
        hr(),
        helpText("Data from AT&T (1961) The World's Telephones.")
      ),

      # Create a spot for the barplot
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("phonePlot")  
      )

    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to do that. If you use a paid version of shinyapps.io then you won't have this bar, but if you're using the free version they add it as advertising because they do need to make some money somehow.

(It is possible to remove it, but I really like RStudio and all their work so I don't want to promote ways to make them lose business, sorry...)

If you look at the different plans and pricing options, it clearly says that the free version includes their logo branding

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove it then you have to pay for it, it's added on the server side. Your other option is to set up a shiny server with Digital Ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-14-04